# How to make login with userid or mobile number using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I created a log-in form with PHP MySQL in that I need to allow user to log-in either with user name or with phone number.

I have this code:-

```
<form method="post" action="">
User name:<input type="text" name="uname" />
PWD:<input type="password" name="pwd" />
<input type="submit" name="sub" />
```

PHP code :

```
<?php 
include "config.php";
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd']; 
$query=mysql_query("select * from users where userId='$uname' and pwd ='$pwd' ");
if($query){
    echo "login success":
}else
echo "login fail";
?>
```

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: You will have to look at tutorials on how to develop log in mechanisms. there are thousands out there. just google it.

Comment: Show us what you have done/tried ?

Comment: How do you login with username? Show us how then we tell you how to login with both

Comment: <?php include "config.php";$uname = $_POST['uname'];$pwd = $_POST['pwd']; $query=mysql_query("select * from users where userId='$uname' and pwd ='$pwd' "); if($query){echo "login success":}else echo "login fail";?><form method="post" action="">
User name:<input type="text" name="uname" />
PWD:<input type="password" name="pwd" />
<input type="submit" name="sub" />

Comment: Hint - phone number will never contain characters. Also don't comment with code, update your question post instead. Paste PHP logic of validation and login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this;

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from users where userId='$uname' and pwd ='$pwd' ");
```

to:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE pwd ='$pwd' AND (userId = '$uname' OR PhoneNum = '$uname')");
```

What this does it will take both **$uname** value and search both Userid column and Phone Num column for a match. Please note that *PhoneNum* is the column name in your table.

Also your database is at risk for attack. MYSQL Injections.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me when i change like this "$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (userId = '$uname' OR PhoneNum = '$uname') AND pwd ='$pwd'");"

Comment: What if user are from different country and has diff area code.